# Word Problem Using elimination and/or substitution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A doctors prescription calls for the creation of pills that contain 12 units of vitamin B and 12 units of vitamin E. Your pharmacy stocks two powders that can be used to make these pills: one contains 20% vitamin B and 30% vitamin E, the other 40% vitamin B and 20% vitamin E. how many units of each powder should be mixed in each pill?

Comment: I think that some information is missing here. Could you doublecheck that you provided all data ? Thanks.

Comment: My try:x=units of powder 1, y=units of powder 2,so, $20x+40y=1200$ and $30x+20y=1200$ gives $x=30$ and $y=15$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the amount of powder 1 taken, which means we are taking x units of powder 1 and that gives $(0.2*x)$ units of vitamin B and $(0.3*x)$ units of vitamin E and

let $y$ is the amount of powder 2 taken, then it gives us $(0.4*y)$ units of vitamin B and $(0.2*y)$ units of vitamin E.

Amount of vitamin B from powder 1 and 2 added together should be $12$.
$\therefore 0.2x+0.4y=12$ and

Amount of vitamin E from powder 1 and 2 added together should be $12$.
$\therefore 0.3x+0.2y=12$

solving the two equations above we get $x=30$ and $y=15$

Therefore, 30 units of powder 1 added with 15 units of powder 2 will give one pill containing 12 units of vitamin B and 12 units of vitamin E.